# Call a Command from a Controller not work

Tags: symfony

i have this code to run schema update command from controller i got help from [symfony document](http://symfony.com/doc/current/console/command_in_controller.html)
i have this code:

```
namespace AdminBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\NullOutput;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/admin")
     */
    public function indexAction(KernelInterface $kernel)
    {
        $application = new Application($kernal);

        $input = new ArrayInput(array(
            'command' => 'doctrine:schema:update'
        ));

        $output = new NullOutput();
        $application->run($input, $output);

        return new Response("");
    }
}
```

it's not work for me i get this error after open this url (http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin):

```
Controller "AdminBundle\Controller\DefaultController::indexAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$kernel" argument. Either the argument is nullable and no null value has been provided, no default value has been provided or because there is a non optional argument after this one.
```

how can i do?

Comment: what symfony version are you using?

Comment: @DanCostinel version 3.3.5

Comment: This isn't why things aren't working, but you have a typo and have `$kernal` instead of `$kernel` in your Controller action.

Comment: and how can i do?

Comment: Did you upgrade from a previous Symfony version to 3.3?  You could be missing config parameters

Comment: You can try the `BufferedOutput` instead of `NullOutput` (and then using `$content = $output->fetch();` and `return new Response($content);` as the docs says, to print any message on the screen. Maybe an error is thrown.

Comment: @jsonroman no its installed with symfony installer

Comment: @A.Seddighi please see my answer for an alternative method.

Comment: I'm using @A.Seddighi's method from Symfony 3.4 docs:
https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/console/command_in_controller.html
The error happens in web/app_dev.php line `$response = $kernel->handle($request);`
Request $request is also being passed in the Controller action... I don't understand why that line is not seeing the request. Our repo was updated from Symfony 2.8 by a previous developer. So I think the documented method will not work on our install because of customizations before the upgrade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of injecting the `KernelInterface $kernel` directly into your action (I guess, you're not using it as a declared service), call your container directly for asking the kernel:

```php
public function indexAction()
{
    $kernel = $this->get('kernel');
    $application = new Application($kernel); // btw: you have an typo in here ($kernal vs $kernel)

    $input = new ArrayInput(array(
        'command' => 'doctrine:schema:update'
    ));

    $output = new NullOutput();
    $application->run($input, $output);

    // tip: use "204 No Content" to indicate "It's successful, and empty"
    return new Response("", 204);
}
```

Comment: The Symfony 3.4 documentation on this -https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/console/command_in_controller.html - mentions using `$application->setAutoExit(false);`... I can't tell if this is necessary for anything, but our repo was upgraded from 2.8 by a previous developer. Also, no matter what I put for Response content, the page returns blank (though the command does run). It's yet another mystery in our repo which does not behave as the documentation says it will in many places, likely due to developer deviations from their own preferred customizations somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

While Michael's answer works, it is not the preferred method in Symfony 3.3, which had several changes to [dependency injection](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html). Your code will actually work just fine with some changes to your services configuration.

As the documentation states, the Dependency Injection Container changed in Symfony 3.3, and by default your [controllers are registered as services](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html#controllers-are-registered-as-services):

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    # ...

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure they're public
    # and have a tag that allows actions to type-hint services
    AppBundle\Controller\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/Controller'
        public: true
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

This allows you to autowire the kernel through arguments in your controller action method, like you tried.  The reason yours isn't working is because your `AdminBundle` is likely not set up the way your `AppBundle` is by default in `app/config/services.yml`.  To truly solve the issue in the way that Symfony 3.3 wants, you should add `AdminBundle` to your services configuration like so:

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    # add this below your AppBundle\Controller definition
    AdminBundle\Controller\:
        resource: '../../src/AdminBundle/Controller'
        public: true
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

With that, you no longer have to call `$this->get('kernel');`, and your original code will work as you have it, with `KernelInterface` as a parameter to your action method.

Furthermore, you can extend the new **[AbstractController](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#controller-abstract-versus-controller)** instead of the regular Controller, and then calls to `$this->get()` will not work anymore, which is the way Symfony is going.

So again while Michael's answer will work just fine, I would advise you to implement the answer I've given simply because Symfony 3.3 prefers that method going forward.

Comment: That's correct too. But since the author didn't provide Symfony's version, I suggested an answer, which works since 2.3 :-)

Comment: Yup both work just great :) He added the version in the comments later so that's why i provided the alternative.